# Why CoordinatorLayout leaves a margin at the bottom?

Tags: android, layout, android-coordinatorlayout, layoutmargins

When I use `layout_height="wrap-content"` in the `CorrdinatorLayout`, there is a margin at the bottom. Here's my code:

```
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         android:id="@+id/activity_details_coordinator_layout"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
         android:background="@color/ui_view_primary_background"
         android:orientation="vertical">

         <include layout="@layout/activity_item_details_appbar_v2"/>

         <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
              android:id="@+id/scrollview_transaction_details_layout"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
              app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
              android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
              android:background="?attr/ui_v2_color_neutral_100">

             <LinearLayout
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:orientation="vertical">

                  <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/transaction_summary"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                        android:orientation="vertical"/>

                  </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

When i change `CoordinatorLayout` height to `match_parent`, it works fine. But, i want to have keep it as `wrap_content`. I have seen many answers that says add `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`to the coordinatorlayout. But, for me, its not working. Any idea why is this happening like this?
[image]
This is the screenshot of my screen. Black area is the `AppBarLayout` and area marked in red is the unwanted margin. Any idea on how to fix this? Thanks